# Evaluating git merge/pull requests: up to date?

Tags: git, gitlab

We use Gitlab and the team members are becoming accustomed to creating branches and then asking our manager of the master branch (often me) to merge onto master. I have a lot of trouble evaluating these proposals, right now I want to just ask about one problem.

A chronic problem is that the workers don't keep their branches up to date with master, so when they push their branch and propose a merge, their proposal may have harmful effects on master.  In a best case scenario, there are merge conflicts and my attention is drawn to trouble spots.  In a bad scenario, Git blends the edits without telling me they are actually not coherent (substantively speaking).

We have a recommended routine they should follow to keep their branch up to date, but sometimes they forget.

As the manager of these merge requests, I have a very difficult time figuring out what to do. In particular, can you help me form a plan to check if a proposed branch is up to date with master before doing anything else?

Let me be specific. I run

```
$ git fetch
```

Then review branches:

```
$ git branch -avv
* master                   f8b10d4 [origin/master] updating: insert discussion
  mc-branch                9d7f005 [origin/mc-branch] mc: added slides   
  remotes/origin/dve    6fd68a0 Upload New File
  remotes/origin/bayes  25ce903 Merge branch 'master' into bayes
  remotes/origin/master    f8b10d4 updating: insert discussion
```

If author of 'mc-branch' proposes a merge, I want to know is that up to date

```
$ git checkout mc-branch
Switched to branch 'mc-branch'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mc-branch'.
```

I'm able to see all of the changes against master with

```
$ git diff master
```

The diff output is a blend of 2 differences.  First, there are the differences between the out of date branch and my current master. Second, there are the substantively important changes the author intends to propose. These blend.  In some cases, it is apparent to me, from inspecting the diff output, that the branch was not up to date with master when author made merge request. But sometimes I can't tell by glancing.

Is there some "easy" "automatic" (brain free!) way for me to tell if the branch was up to date when author proposed it? If branch is out of date, I'd like to kill the merge request without spending any more time. I'll tell the author to fix it.

I don't see an easy way to tell in gitlab if a branch is up to date.

Comment: There's nothing built in to Git itself that's that easy. I have not used GitLab and don't know what it offers. GitHub sell their service by offering buttons / displays that *do* make it that easy (but in the process of doing so, hide a lot of Git complexity that could matter to you, perhaps).

Comment: Doesn't gitlab provide you a UI which shows you just author's changes?